# Can we create module in prestashop 1.6 using modular approach?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Is it possible to create module which follow the modular approach?
Can we also create custom hook in Prestashop 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop Version 1.6 you are able to create your own custom hooks.

In your module.php install() function you can register a new custom hook like this:

`$this->registerHook('NameOfHook');`

To assign the hook e.g. in a template file. You just need to add the following code:

`{hook h='NameOfHook' mod='yourModuleName'}`

Note: In version 1.6 its not neccessary anymore to insert the hook into the hooks table. Presta will do this automatically if the registered hook doesn't exists now.

For the modular approach please have a look at the following links:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Coding+Standards

Some other usefull links for you might be:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks